# Determine version of Phusion Passenger on managed server

Tags: apache, passenger, managed

I'm going to host an app on a managed server.How to show the current version of Phusion Passenger running on that machine?

Answer (score 0):

```
passenger -v
gem list |grep passenger
```

Comment: "command not found". Probably cannot access this being on a managed server. Will ask the host company directly, but thanks mikhailov!